# Merge [blogger] with [blogspot]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

[blogger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogger) and [blogspot](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogspot) are about the same service. Please make them synonymous.

Answer (score 6):

Merged all questions tagged [blogspot](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogspot) to [blogger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogger) and added a synonym for future questions.